# Reuse image description (alt text) as hover tooltip (title) by default

Tags: feature-request, markdown, images, tooltips

As [What's the point in adding alt-text to an image?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144080/whats-the-point-in-adding-alt-text-to-an-image) explains, currently, image description text only shows when browsing with images disabled

- and as such, can't be seen at all (and thus is useless) in the vast majority of cases.
- But, it is still inserted automatically into every image added with the toolbar button.
- As a consequence, most leave it as is or delete altogether.

On the other hand (as shown in the same topic), Markdown allows to set the `<img>`'s `title` as well which shows as a tooltip when hovering the image -

- pretty helpful.
- However, since this feature is buried in the Markdown docs, few know of this.
- In any case, it requires additional manipulations
- and duplicates the field with the same purpose that's already there.

  - (I've read all sorts of SEO papers which describe the nuances between them. Still, I assert that for all purposes of SE posts, they do the same thing.)

So, I'm suggesting to:

> Reuse `alt` as `title` unless the latter is specified explicitly.

(Of course, the same can be achieved with JS, but I don't see a need when there's an easy static way. All in all, implementation details aren't that important).

Some references:

- [How To Optimize Alt and Title Text on Images - Raven Blog](https://raventools.com/blog/alt-title-text-optimized-images/)
- [Image SEO Optimization - Improve your search rankings](http://madlemmings.com/2013/07/15/image-seo-optimization-how-to-improve-your-search-rankings/)
- [HTML img tag: title attribute vs. alt attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872389/html-img-tag-title-attribute-vs-alt-attribute)
- [Proxomitron](http://proxomitron.ru) has a stock filter for exactly what I'm suggesting

Some previous discussions (apart from what is already linked):

- [Also use alt tag as title on images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35995/also-use-alt-tag-as-title-on-images)
- [Can we get rid of the default text "enter image description here"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88756/can-we-get-rid-of-the-default-text-enter-image-description-here)
- [Add Image Captions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142750/add-image-captions)